# How can I extract the Matrix data from a mesh?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I drew a mesh in Matlab. The data for the mesh was supplied with a filled 3d Matrix. Nothing special with that.

I saved the created figure and came back to it now.
I want to create a different plot with the same data. Is there a way to extract the matrix data from the mesh so I can reuse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some luck, following solution could work:

Load the figure file:
`fig = openfig('fig_file_name.fig');`

Get the surface data from the axes of the figure (assuming surface is the first "children"):
`s = fig.CurrentAxes.Children(1);`

Look for your data in `s.XData`, `s.YData` and `s.ZData`.

---

Better solution is using `findobj` (instead of `fig.CurrentAxes.Children(1)`) use:

`s = findobj(fig, 'type', 'Surface');`

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you very much. I went for the findobj solution which worked immediately